# Swift reusable model class/struct

Tags: swift

I have a service whose response vary based on the orderNumer(input parameter which I pass to service). all most all object are same but only one object(ex meta object which is dictionary)vary based on order number. But I would like to reuse the same model class everywhere but due to different meta object can't be able to create that meta object in model class.I can achieve it by creating individual model class but not a right solution.

```
struct BookingInfo: Codable {
        let created_time: Int
        // Some other 20 key value pairs
        let oms_meta: Meta  /* oms_meta": {
            "package": {
                "description": "gzhdjjdjd"
            }*/

    }
    // Meta for Order1
    struct Meta: Codable {
        let package: Description
        enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case package = "package"
        }
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            package = try values.decode(Description.self, forKey: .package)
        }
    }

    // Meta for Order 2
    struct Meta: Codable {
        let customer_payment_details: Int
        let items: Int // this can be anything dictinary or some time array of dictionary

        enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case package = "customer_payment_details"
            case items = "items"
        }
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            customer_payment_details = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .package)
            items = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .package)

        }
    }
Only meta parameters are varying from service to service.

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Could you provide your code? It will be much easier to understand the problem.

Comment: Quoting your question: "All object are same but only one". You want to threat them like a single object, but they are not. Is there a specific reason to not create a specific data model for the different one, except personal feelings?

Comment: But what do you want, you haven't asked a question?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson What I'm asking is OrderModel class have name, image, number and orderDescription, in that orderDescription is a dictionary that's varying from one service response to another, But remaining name, number and image is same, so I would like to use the same OrderModel class for all services. hope I'm able to give clear information

Comment: @MarcoPace there is no reason not to use different model classes, it's just a personal feeling. I feel like there is smell in service response format.

Comment: Then add that information to your question and preferable also some code to further clarify what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only use 1 model, you should provide a variable for all the possible keys in the dictionary and set them as optional.

Let's say all orders have an orderNumber, but only some have an orderImage you could do it like this:

`struct Order: Codable {
    var orderNumber: Int
    var orderImage: Data?
    var orderName: String?
    var orderDescription: String?
}`

This way, the returned data only has to contain an orderNumber to be able to decode it.

Edit: You'd have to make a seperate model for each type of 'meta data' as they seem to be very different from eachother. Note that there is nothing wrong with creating a lot of model classes as long as they represent a specific data object.

Comment: let's  say orderDescription is a dictionary whose key values vary and also dictionary structure entirely diffreent from service to service but yet (number, image, name) remain same.how should I use the same Order model class for all services

Comment: Try to give me 2 examples of how 2 orders might look.

Comment: updated code, Single Booking info model class with two different kind of meta Object. I feel like there is smell in response else I have to go with individual Model class. Just wanted to reuse the code so.

Comment: I thought so but json decoding fail for separate meta data, So end up creating separate Model classes.Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  {
    "created_time": 1,
    "oms_meta": {
    "name": "1"
    }
  },
  {
   "created_time": 1,
   "oms_meta": [
   1
]
}
]
```

Suppose we have a response something like this, where you can have multiple `oms_meta` objects. So what we can do here is to specify an `enum` which will contain both `array` as well as `dictionary`, it doesn't matter if the service sends you `array` or `dictionary` if you need to specify other `data types` mentioned it in that enum. So it will be like,

```
struct BookingInfoElement: Codable {
    let createdTime: Int?
    let omsMeta: OmsMetaUnion?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case createdTime = "created_time"
        case omsMeta = "oms_meta"
    }
}

enum OmsMetaUnion: Codable {
    case integerArray([Int])
    case omsMetaClass(OmsMetaClass)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode([Int].self) {
            self = .integerArray(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(OmsMetaClass.self) {
            self = .omsMetaClass(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(OmsMetaUnion.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for OmsMetaUnion"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .integerArray(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .omsMetaClass(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

struct OmsMetaClass: Codable {
    let name: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
    }
}

typealias BookingInfo = [BookingInfoElement]
```

So, if you specifically want to have multiple types for a single variable you can create another enum with that multiple types and assign accordingly. You can access that variable using `switch` like, and check on `array` and `dictionary` types.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some analyses I found the solution for my requirement. As I wanted to reuse the Model class and OMS_Meta dictionary different from product to product, I'm adding omsMeta to JSONDecoder().userInfo property

```
   struct BookingInfo: Codable {
          let created_time: Int
          let oms_meta: [String: Any]
        }
        public static let metaUserInfo = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "oms_meta")!
        decoder.userInfo[BookingInfo.metaUserInfo] = jsonDecode
```

By doing this I can re use my model class.